# How to use predicate with generic in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types, predicate

I want to use array filtering predicate function

e.g.

`const isNotEmptyName = <T extends { name: string | null }>(value: T): value is { name: string } => Boolean(value.name);`

But, in this case I have an error about

```
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    '{ name: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ name: string | null; }'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAciKBRAtgBygT0QQ3QFMYBeGAHgBUYiAPKIsAEwhgG8YxCiAuGaACc4YAOYwAPlwCuAG1kwAvgD4AFADd8s6XxhUAlP03aSCDlx78hI8YrLKAsACgYrt+9cAhECFlF8YBpaOgB03MT6QA

Comment: If you make the function generic, `name` might be *narrower* than `string`, so `{name: string}` might be *wider* than `T`, and thus your predicate is too wide. You can fix that either by making the result something like `T & {name: string}` or by making the function non-generic (which is essentially the same as the intersection).  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXlEQw). Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: What are you expecting `value is { name: string }` to do?,   it's not required anyway.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Keith
I have many objects with property "name" which may be is null and because of this I have to check property

Comment: `I have to check property`  `Is` won't runtime check this, you need a type guard at runtime for this.  `if ('name' in value) {....`

Comment: @Keith
No, I am sorry for my first answer to you, your solution is right, but for another case. I did wrong when said to you not whole context, so I have some array `Array<{name: string | null}> and I need in Array<{name: string}>`. 
I want to use **filter** function, and I need a **predicate** function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really done anything wrong, but TypeScript requires that for a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) of the form `val is Type`, the type of `val` must be assignable to `Type` to start with, so that `val is Type` is seen as a *narrowing*.  And the reason TypeScript complains about `value is {name: string}` is that someone might call `isNotEmptyName()` on a value whose name property is narrower than `string | null`, such as one using string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) instead of `string`:

```
interface Foo {
    name: "hello" | "goodbye" | null;
    age: number;
}
declare const foo: Foo;
isNotEmptyName(foo);
```

And in that case, `{name: string}` is considered in error, since `string` is not a narrowing of `"hello" | "goodbye" | null`.

---

The easiest fix is to remove generics entirely from your function, since it will behave as desired without them:

```
const isNotEmptyName = (value: { name: string | null }):
    value is { name: string } =>
    Boolean(value.name)
```

That compiles because `{name: string}` is narrower than `{name: string | null}`, and when you use it the compiler figures out what the resulting type of the input should be:

```
if (isNotEmptyName(foo)) {
    foo // const foo: Foo & { name: string; }
    foo.name.toUpperCase(); // okay
}
```

You can see that `foo` has been narrowed from `Foo` to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `Foo & {name: string}`, meaning that `foo` has to be both of those.  And indeed, the type of `foo.name` has been narrowed to `"hello" | "goodbye"` without `null`, and you can dereference it with `toUpperCase()` safely.

---

If for some reason you need to keep it generic, you can get the same effect by manually writing the type predicate to refer to the intersection:

```
const isNotEmptyName = <T extends { name: string | null }>(value: T):
    value is T & { name: string } =>
    Boolean(value.name)
```

That compiles because `T` is definitely assignable to `T & U` for any `U` including `{name: string}`.  And it works the same when you call it:

```
if (isNotEmptyName(foo)) {
    foo // const foo: Foo & { name: string; }
    foo.name.toUpperCase(); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyIcAthAFzIBEAFhADaPo3IA+tA5pgCYBGATwhtOIAK7MA3AWLI4XKiXFl+0GfgC+BXhASM4UFAnQgAzmGQxM1DOg0FSFMwAdEKAEJxeOWcRPmlsBmAHLoYACiZC5ggiHkKAC8yAA8ACrIEAAekCC8ZjgkCdQWUKBcHMrMyJoAfAAUAG5wjOJKaQCU1M2tKMGFTkql5TXIibV+ckQemIwQcCBNLW0AdIMdBNr4jgmu7shhIADiECC+24T+phbIwWGR0bHxFGPIS73U2EUUJWBlIBUxJJGDUupMpj02rcCl9Br9-hVNGMJpcpsgZug5gt3qt1gRwcAYG87uEojE4gl6tZ0B0Ouc0URqcgAPTM5ABG7U2yYZAAMgGxWQwwBUhq4Lk1LWCRWYHQAFUXC5oABhOBmCD1Dqi1nIdAAazggnBWy2O2cbiQyBOZzwFzkHKCoVJjwpL2S6UyOVO+QFPyFfxGQOqdRx7TBqIhyz6BQy-NhguFiOR4uIGKxi0hEClFA2duIhOJToe5OeGuptPpDKZOodVhsaB5ce+QwDIrFEYlmGzWdlCqVUFV6s12rZ+sNxvxFy2QA)